# Log out with Spotipy library

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to write an app, that will allow people to login and get access to their playlists.
But I'm having a problem when I'm trying to log out from account of previous user: It simple stays with the same access_token and have access to previous account. How can I fix it?

```
import spotipy
import os
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

username = 'user'
scope = 'playlist-read-collaborative playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private'

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLIENT_ID',
                            client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET', username=username,
                            redirect_uri='http://google.com/', scope=scope)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
cache_path = f".cache-{username}"
if os.path.exists(cache_path):
    os.remove(cache_path)

if auth_manager.get_access_token() is not None:
    print(f"User {username} is logged in.")

    user_info = sp.current_user()
    print(f"User ID: {user_info['id']}")
else:
    print(f"User {username} is not logged in.")


def get_playlists():
    user = sp.current_user()
    current_playlists = sp.user_playlists(user['id'])['items']

    playlist_with_items = {}
    for playlist in current_playlists:
        playlist_with_items[playlist['name']] = []
        for pl in sp.playlist_items(playlist['id'])['items']:
            playlist_with_items[playlist['name']].append(
                pl['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name'] + '-' + pl['track']['name'])

    return playlist_with_items


def parser(link: str):
    i = 0
    playlist_id = ''
    while i < len(link):
        if link[i:i + 17] == 'open.spotify.com/':
            i += 17
            if link[i] == 'p':
                i += 9
                while i < len(link) and link[i] != '/':
                    playlist_id += link[i]
                    i += 1
                if playlist_id:
                    return playlist_id
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Playlist ID not found")
            else:
                break
        i += 1
    raise ValueError("Invalid link")


def get_playlist_by_url(pl_id):
    current_playlist = sp.playlist_items(pl_id)
    playlist_with_items = []
    for track in current_playlist['items']:
        playlist_with_items.append(track['track']['album']['artists'][0]['name'] + '-' + track['track']['name'])
    return playlist_with_items


def search_create_add(query: list):
    uris = []
    needed_id = None
    for i in query:
        ur = sp.search(i)['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
        uris.append(ur)
    print(uris)
    sp.user_playlist_create(user_info['id'], name='New_try')
    for playlist in sp.current_user_playlists()['items']:
        if (playlist['name'] == 'New_try'):
            needed_id = playlist['id']
    sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=needed_id, items=uris)
```

Tried to clear cash, but it doesn't help(

Comment: So how exactly are you "trying to log out", did you implement anything specific within your app for that, or what _exactly_ does it mean?

Comment: I'm trying to clean cash from the app

Comment: You're not trying to launder money here, so the word you were looking for is "cache" :-) But clearing that for your app, won't do much when it comes to OAuth. As long as the user is still logged in to the Spotify website, they will be automatically get logged in to your app again, the next time you invoke the login flow. You need to explicitly log them out - either via the Spotify SDK/library you are using there, if that offers any such functionality; or you will have to tell your app users to _explicitly_ go to the website and log out there, when they are done using your app.

Comment: I added syntax highlighting to your post by including the `python` tag, which revealed a pretty obvious quoting problem. Is that in your original code? Please make sure to share _accurate_ code. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos.